# Как удалить элементы из списка при условии, что они не имеют определенного знака?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например :

```
lst = ['123','341','523']
```

А должно стать:

```
lst = ['123','341']
```

'523' - не подходит потому што там нету знака '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ['123','341','523']
lst = [str for str in lst if '1' in str]
print(lst)
```